# How to complete fill Table Header with color?

Tags: html, css

I have a html css Table and want that my Header Row has a background color. This is my code.

```
<table class="contentTable">
    <tr class="contentTableHeader">
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Dienstleistung</th>
        <th>Stunden</th>
        <th>Preis</th>
        <th>Netto</th>
    </tr>
 ....
```

My css

```
     .contentTable {
         padding-top: 10mm;
         table-layout: auto;
         width: 100%;
         max-width: 100%;

     }
     .contentTable th{
         font-size: medium;
     }
     .contentTable td{
         font-size: small;
     }

     .contentTableHeader {
         background-color: cornflowerblue;
         color:azure;
     }
```

The Problem is, that the Cell "separators" are still white. How to make header row complete same color?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `border-spacing` property to tabel. Set it to 0px

```css
.contentTable {
    padding-top: 10mm;
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.contentTable th {
    font-size: medium;
}

.contentTable td {
    font-size: small;
}

.contentTableHeader {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: azure;
}
```

```html
<table class="contentTable">
  <tr class="contentTableHeader">
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Dienstleistung</th>
    <th>Stunden</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
    <th>Netto</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```